# How can I use VSO downloader

Tags: 12.04, video

I downloaded VSO downloader and tried to install it, but I don't know how to do that. I also tried to use Wine to run it, without succes. I don't know if it is possible at all to install it.

Is there a way I can use VSO downloader on Ubuntu?

Comment: What is VSO? It has a Linux/Ubuntu version? Have you tried just to install it?

Answer (score 0):

VSO Downloader is a Windows program for Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows 8. You can download the program from http://www.vso-software.fr/products/downloader/vso-downloader.php using a web browser like Chrome or Firefox. Windows programs don't work on Ubuntu, but you may be able to run it within Wine.

To install Wine type in the Terminal `sudo apt-get install wine`. To install a program in wine just right click on the installer .exe file and choose "open with wine programs loader". Typically the archive manager is default for .exe files which is why you can't just double click them. There is no guarantee that the program will work in Wine, and it won't be able to use your Linux web browser so you will also need to install a supported browser in Wine.

You should install the browser before you install VSO Downloader so that it will be able to detect it. VSO Downloader supports all the major browsers like Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Internet Explorer, and even Safari.